# How do I extract data from a DataTable?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a `DataTable` that is filled in from an SQL query to a local database, but I don't know how to extract data from it.
Main method (in test program):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string connectionString = "server=localhost\\SQLExpress;database=master;integrated Security=SSPI;";
    DataTable table = new DataTable("allPrograms");

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connection created successfuly");

        string command = "SELECT * FROM Programs";

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("command created successfuly");

            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            conn.Open(); 
            Console.WriteLine("connection opened successfuly");
            adapt.Fill(table);
            conn.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("connection closed successfuly");
        }
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

The command I used to create the tables in my database:

```sql
create table programs
(
    progid int primary key identity(1,1),
    name nvarchar(255),
    description nvarchar(500),
    iconFile nvarchar(255),
    installScript nvarchar(255)
)
```

How can I extract data from the `DataTable` into a form meaningful to use?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The DataTable has a collection `.Rows` of DataRow elements.

Each DataRow corresponds to one row in your database, and contains a collection of columns.

In order to access a single value, do something like this:

```
 foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
 { 
     string name = row["name"].ToString();
     string description = row["description"].ToString();
     string icoFileName = row["iconFile"].ToString();
     string installScript = row["installScript"].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but don't you need to do a cast in the foreach loop to allow indexing?  I wasn't able to do something like this until I changed the code to look like the following:

foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
...

Comment: Even older comment, but there's no need to cast: `foreach` works, because `Rows` is a collection (`DataRowCollection`). Though, you need to use `.Cast<DataRow>()` if you want to use some Linq methods (`.Where()`, for an example).

Answer (score 27):

You can set the datatable as a datasource to many elements.

For eg

gridView

repeater

datalist

etc etc

If you need to extract data from each row then you can use

```
table.rows[rowindex][columnindex]
```

or

if you know the column name

```
table.rows[rowindex][columnname]
```

If you need to iterate the table then you can either use a for loop or a foreach loop like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i ++ )
{
    string name = table.rows[i]["columnname"].ToString();
}

foreach ( DataRow dr in table.Rows )
{
    string name = dr["columnname"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: foreach ( DataRow dr in table )

table.Rows

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way to extract data from a `DataTable` when you have multiple data types (not just strings) is to use the `Field<T>` extension method available in the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` assembly.

```
var id = row.Field<int>("ID");         // extract and parse int
var name = row.Field<string>("Name");  // extract string
```

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2), the `Field<T>` method:

> Provides strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the
>   DataRow.

This means that when you specify the type it will validate and unbox the object.

For example:

```
// iterate over the rows of the datatable
foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())  // AsEnumerable() returns IEnumerable<DataRow>
{
    var id = row.Field<int>("ID");                           // int
    var name = row.Field<string>("Name");                    // string
    var orderValue = row.Field<decimal>("OrderValue");       // decimal
    var interestRate = row.Field<double>("InterestRate");    // double
    var isActive = row.Field<bool>("Active");                // bool
    var orderDate = row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate");        // DateTime
}
```

It also supports nullable types:

```
DateTime? date = row.Field<DateTime?>("DateColumn");
```

This can simplify extracting data from `DataTable` as it removes the need to explicitly convert or parse the object into the correct types.

Answer (score 6):

Please consider using some code like this:

```cs
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int numRows = 0;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Load(reader);
numRows = dt.Rows.Count;

string attended_type = "";

for (int index = 0; index < numRows; index++)
{
    attended_type = dt.Rows[indice2]["columnname"].ToString();
}

reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a specific reason to do raw ado.net I would have a look at using an ORM (object relational mapper) like nHibernate or LINQ to SQL. That way you can query the database and retrieve objects to work with which are strongly typed and easier to work with IMHO.

Comment: I'm getting a basic knowledge of ADO.net before moving on to an ORM as suggested by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345508/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-database-from-c/1345531#1345531

Answer (score -1):

```
  var table = Tables[0]; //get first table from Dataset
  foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
       foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
         {
            console.Write("Value:"+item);
         }
     }
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation. Code-only answers are rarely useful in the long term.

Answer (score -1):

Please, note that Open and Close the connection is not necessary when using DataAdapter.

So I suggest please update this code and remove the open and close of the connection:

```
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

> conn.Open(); // this line of code is uncessessary

```
        Console.WriteLine("connection opened successfuly");
        adapt.Fill(table);
```

> conn.Close(); // this line of code is uncessessary

```
        Console.WriteLine("connection closed successfuly");
```

[Reference Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter)

> The code shown in this example does not explicitly open and close the
>   Connection. The Fill method implicitly opens the Connection that the
>   DataAdapter is using if it finds that the connection is not already
>   open. If Fill opened the connection, it also closes the connection
>   when Fill is finished. This can simplify your code when you deal with
>   a single operation such as a Fill or an Update. However, if you are
>   performing multiple operations that require an open connection, you
>   can improve the performance of your application by explicitly calling
>   the Open method of the Connection, performing the operations against
>   the data source, and then calling the Close method of the Connection.
>   You should try to keep connections to the data source open as briefly
>   as possible to free resources for use by other client applications.

Comment: This does not address the question at all.