# Looping through rows in DataTable and extracting element in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I want to extract items of the column in DataTable and put them in List.

This are my List and DataTable:

```
List<int> product1 = new List<int>();
DataTable table = this.IoC.Resolve<ISurveyResultsService>().GetProduct(studyYear, productName);
```

I want to loop through the DataTable and put elements in the list. I tried like this:

```
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
    product.Add((int)row["StudyID"]);
}
```

I get an error "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"

Any idea how to fix that as simple as possible?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346132/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-datatable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast it in the foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
```

Note that type definition in a foreach acts as a cast. Now you have a type that allows `[]`.

---

You can also use **Linq** to make it look cleaner:

```
List<int> product = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => (int)row["StudyID"]).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    product.Add((int)row["StudyID"]);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
{
    product.Add((int)row["StudyID"]);
}
```

or

```
products = table.AsEnumerable().Select(row=>(int)row["StudyID"]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are converting table row as `var` object.Convert it as `DataRow`
try

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    product.Add((int)row["StudyID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
  Person p=new Person();
  foreach(DataRow row in YourDataTable.Rows)
  { 
   p.name = row["name"].ToString();
   p.description = row["description"].ToString();
   lst.Add(p);

}
```

lst is list<.Person>

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the var row with DataRow row:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            product.Add((int)row["StudyID"]);
        }
```