# How To Extract Values From DataTable To List in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I Have A Purchase Invoice Form That is Called PurchaseInvoiceForm. I Have A DataGridView In It And Also Used A List To Store Items So I Saved The Data In The Database Successfully.But Whenever I Want To Load Data Back To Form Everything is Fine Excepts I unable To Extract Data From DataTable And Load Back To PurchaseInvoiceCart That is a List.So Here The Code.

```
    foreach (DataTable row in dtPurchaseInvoice)
        {
            PurchaseInvoice i = new PurchaseInvoice();
            i.PurchaseInvoiceNo =Convert.ToInt32(row["PurchaseInvoiceNo"]);              
        }
```

Comment: try dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows

Comment: foreach (DataRow row in dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346132/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-datatable)

Comment: DataRow item in dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows  //It Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract data from a data table use the `.Field<T>()` extension method from `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`. Please see the documentation [DataRow.Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2).

You need to create a list of type `PurchaseInvoice` and iterate over the `DataRow` collection `table.Rows`.

Please see example below:

```
// create a list for your invoices
List<PurchaseInvoice> invoices = new List<PurchaseInvoice>();

foreach (DataRow row in dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows)
{   //                                   ^ Rows
    // create invoice
    PurchaseInvoice invoice = new PurchaseInvoice();

    // get an int
    invoice.PurchaseInvoiceNo = row.Field<int>("PurchaseInvoiceNo"); 

    // get a string
    invoice.CustomerName = row.Field<string>("CustomerName");

    // get a DateTime
    invoice.PurchaseDate = row.Field<DateTime>("PurchaseDate");

    // get a double
    invoice.PurchaseValue = row.Field<double>("PurchaseValue");

    // add invoice to list     
    invoices.Add(invoice);
}
```

Using `.Field<T>()` extension means you do not need to convert/cast the object into the correct type - it is handled by the extension for you.

It also works with nullable fields:

```
DateTime? date = row.Field<DateTime?>("PurchaseDate");
```

Comment: Thanks Dear It Works.

Comment: @FarooqAhmed please accept my answer if it solved the issue :)

Comment: @FarooqAhmed look at the tick next to each answer. Click the tick/check next to the answer you like best.  See [how to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows)
    {
        PurchaseInvoice i = new PurchaseInvoice();
        i.PurchaseInvoiceNo =Convert.ToInt32(row["PurchaseInvoiceNo"]);              
    }
```

Comment: And as oneliner: dtPurchaseInvoice.Rows.Select(new PurchaseInvoice{.PurchaseInvoiceNo =Convert.ToInt32(row["PurchaseInvoiceNo"])}).ToList();

Comment: Alfons I have multiple parameters upto 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way.

```
List<PurchaseInvoice> objPurchaseInvoiceList = new  List<PurchaseInvoice>();
foreach (DataTable row in dtPurchaseInvoice)
{
    objPurchaseInvoiceList.add(new  PurchaseInvoice{ PurchaseInvoiceNo=Convert.ToInt32(row["PurchaseInvoiceNo"])});                  
}
```

Comment: It can be helpful but i have multiple  parameters upto 8.

Comment: @FarooqAhmed so you are unable fulfill your requirement with help of this ?