# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The title is the error I keep getting, I have been following a tutorial for a uni project of mine. However, I hit a stage where I need to make CRUD operations. This is the error I am given: **The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable**. 
And here is the rest of it:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Quilted_Bear_Inventory_Management_System.Models.Products]'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataRow]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Quilted_Bear_Inventory_Management_System.Models.Products]'.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +107
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +99
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +198
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecute>b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9836613
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

## This is my code from my ProductsController:

```
namespace Quilted_Bear_Inventory_Management_System.Controllers
{
    public class ProductsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Products
        readonly string myConnectionString = "server = ; user = ; password = ; database = ";

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SelectAllProducts", myConnection); //I think the problem is here, how am I fixing it though? --Fixed but why can't it be put into a class?
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

            return View(dataTable.AsEnumerable().ToList());
        }
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateProduct(Products product)
        {
            //insert statement
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public bool Delete(int ID)
        {
            try
            {
                //delete statement where id = id
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Update(int ID)
        {
            //update view where id is id
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateDoctor(Products product)
        {
            //update statement
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Doctors");
        }
    }
}
```

## Last but not least my Products Index Page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}
@model IEnumerable<Quilted_Bear_Inventory_Management_System.Models.Products>
<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        Products
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Products</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Manage Products</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product ID</th>
                                <th>SKU</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Unit Price</th>
                                <th>Units in Stock</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SKU)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPriceProduct)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsInStock)</td>
                                    <td><a href="Products/Update/@item.ProductID">Update</a> | <a href="" onclick="Delete('@item.ProductID')">Delete</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</section>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script src="~/bower_components/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/bower_components/datatables.net-bs/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- page script -->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#example1').DataTable();
    });
    function Delete(id){
        var txt;
        var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
        if (r == true) {

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Doctors")',
                data: {
                    id: id
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        var baseUrl="/Doctors";
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("There is a problem, Try Later!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated, I am lost. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you build your view to accept a collection of `Models.Products` but you are passing it a collection of datarows. Do you have a method to convert a datarow to an object? Or should you use EF os another framework to create entities from a data source?

Comment: @DStanley Hey, thanks for the reply. I don't really get what you mean. I was hoping that I can send off the data table and the view will loop around everything in that table, is this not possible?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd need to redesign your view to process datarows. Seems like you've mixed two turorials - one to build the view from objects (whicih is cleaner) and one to get data. Honestly I'd either switch to EF or write a conversion method to create an object from a DataRow.

Comment: @DStanley Ah, I get what you mean now, I do actually have EntityFramework installed through NuGet. So what am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: construct a list of ``Products`` for all ``Datable.Rows`` and send it to the ``View``, [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346132/how-do-i-extract-data-from-a-datatable) will help you to get data from ``Rows``

Comment: @Sajid Oh, I think I am starting to get it, so data rows work hand-in hand with DataTables. That's handy. I will give that a go and come back with my findings. Cheers chief!